# Please help me on this javascript to change the no-image image for my blog

Tags: javascript, blogger

Here is the javascript. It is from my blog. I have used blog theme created by someone to my blog. This javascript embeds the default no-image for those articles that has no image. I want to display my own default no-image for those articles but I could not figure out how do it through this script. Please help.

Javascript looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?
String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]
=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])
p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(s,n){c s.d(/<.*?>/e,\'\').
f(/\\s+/).g(0,n-1).h(\' \')}6 i(a){j p=k.l(a),3=\'\',2=p.m(\'2\');o(2.q>=1){3=\'<24="8" 
5="\'+2[0].5+\'" />\'}r{3=\'<2 4="8" 5="t://u.v.w/-x/y-z/A/B-C/D.E" />\'}p.9=\'<b 4="F-G-H">
\'+3+\'<p>\'+7(p.9,I)+\'...</p>    </b>\'}',45,45,'||img|imgtag|class|src|function|stripTags|thumb
|innerHTML||div|return|replace|ig|split|slice|join|readmore|var|document|getElementById|
getElementsByTagName||if||length|else||https|lh4|googleusercontent|com|G9M2DTCTUwM|Tlh|
2pwtc5I|AAAAAAAABKM|kCJg|Kf3W2M|no_image_yet|jpg|post|excerpt|text|40'.split('|'),0,{}))
//]]></script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Oh and that Javascript looks like its been minified, so good luck changing it.

Comment: The image used on above javascript is "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-G9M2DTCTUwM/Tlh-2pwtc5I/AAAAAAAABKM/kCJg-Kf3W2M/no_image_yet.jpg". I want to put my own image in place of that. Any suggestion?

Comment: can u give the link of the blog containing this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you could observe,

> https://
>   lh4.googleusercontent.com/-G9M2DTCTUwM/Tlh-2pwtc5I/AAAAAAAABKM/kCJg-Kf3W2M/no_image_yet.jpg

is implemented using following code in JS.

```
https|lh4|googleusercontent|com|G9M2DTCTUwM|Tlh|2pwtc5I|AAAAAAAABKM|kCJg|Kf3W2M|no_image_yet|jpg
```

Just Upload your image to blogger, and get the link. replace the data with your new image.